# What's the marginal density of Y?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am learning probability theory and trying to do some exercises by myself. A question I encounter:

Suppose that $Y|X$ is uniform on $[0,x]$ and that $X$ is marginally uniform on $[0,1]$. What's the marginal density of $Y$?

Since $X$ is marginally uniform on $[0,1]$, we know that $f(X) = 1 \implies f(X,Y) = \frac{1}{x}$ on $[0,1] $ and $0$ otherwise. But this means
$$ f_Y(y) = \int^1_0{f(X,Y)dx} = \int^1_0{\frac{1}{x}dx} = ln(1) - ln(0) =????$$ which is where I am stuck at.

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability density function of $X$ is $f_X(x)=\mathbf{1}_{\{0\leq x\leq 1\}}$. Also, the conditional probability density of $Y$ given $X$ is $f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{1}{x}\mathbf{1}_{\{0<y\leq x\}}$, for $y\in (0,1]$. Because $y$ is a continuous random variable, the value of $f_{Y|X}$ at $y=0$ can be set arbitrarily. It follows that for $y\in (0,1$],

$$f_X(x)f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{1}{x}\mathbf{1}_{\{0<y\leq x,0\leq x\leq 1\}}.$$
We then find that for a fixed $y\in (0,1]$,

$$f_Y(y)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\mathbf{1}_{\{0<y\leq x,0\leq x\leq 1\}}dx=\int_y^1\frac{1}{x}dx=-\ln(y),$$
which is the marginal probability density function of $Y$.

Comment: oh yes of course! I was so stupid. I didn't realize the support of Y. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!